# spinor representation

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, spin-geometry

I am trying to study Special unitary group of order 2 and some textbooks mention objects transform under special unitary group are called Spinors then  How can we represent a spinor using matrix ?

Comment: In quantum mechanics spinors are represented as column vectors. The thing that makes them spinors is the way the components of the column vector mix when a coordinate rotation occurs.

Comment: So according to you for SU (2) Spinor is a 2 by 1 matrix , isn't it ? @ Spencer

Comment: Yes a spinor can be represented that way.

Comment: Can spinors be 2 by 2 under SU (2) @ Spencer

Comment: Did I manage to answer your question?

Comment: Your answer is helpful @ Spencer

Answer (score 1):

$SU(2)$ can be defined as the group of determinant-$1$ transformations which leaves,

$$ | z_1 |^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1,$$

invariant.

The transformations themselves act on the two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$. It is common to represent $z_1$ and $z_2$ as the two components of a complex column vector,

$$ \left(\begin{array} \ z_1 \\ z_2 \end{array}\right),$$

but there is nothing to prevent us from representing these complex numbers in a $2\times 2$ matrix.

In particular the actual elements of $SU(2)$ can be thought of as spinors. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) we have the group elements of $SU(2)$ can be represented as

$$ \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha & - \bar{\beta} \\ \beta & \bar{\alpha} \end{array}\right) \qquad |\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1,$$

notice that this matrix is determined by only two complex numbers which satisfy the same normalization as the $z_1$ and $z_2$ indicated previously. In fact this matrix is completely determined by the spinor in its first column.

---

To see that the representation is really faithful let us compare the action of group elements when they act on our spinors.

$$ \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha & - \bar{\beta} \\ \beta & \bar{\alpha} \end{array}\right) \left( \begin{array} \ z_1 \\ z_2\end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha z_1 - \bar{\beta} z_2 \\ \beta z_1 + \bar{\alpha} z_2\end{array}\right)$$

Now consider the other transformation:

$$ \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha & - \bar{\beta} \\ \beta & \bar{\alpha} \end{array}\right) \left( \begin{array} \ z_1 & - \bar{z_2} \\ z_2 & \bar{z_1} \end{array}\right)$$

$$ = \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha z_1 - \bar{\beta} z_2 &  -\alpha \bar{z_2} - \bar{\beta} \bar{z_1} \\ \beta z_1 + \bar{\alpha} z_2 & -\beta \bar{z_2} + \bar{\alpha} \bar{z_1} \end{array}\right) $$

$$ = \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha z_1 - \bar{\beta} z_2 &  \overline{ -\bar{\alpha} z_2 - \beta z_1} \\ \beta z_1 + \bar{\alpha} z_2 & \overline{-\bar{\beta} z_2 + \alpha z_1 } \end{array}\right) $$

$$ = \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha z_1 - \bar{\beta} z_2 &  -\overline{\left( \bar{\alpha} z_2 + \beta z_1\right)} \\ \beta z_1 + \bar{\alpha} z_2 & \overline{ \alpha z_1 -\bar{\beta} z_2  } \end{array}\right)      $$

$$ = \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha z_1 - \bar{\beta} z_2 &  -\overline{\left(  \beta z_1 + \bar{\alpha} z_2 \right)} \\ \beta z_1 + \bar{\alpha} z_2 & \overline{ \alpha z_1 -\bar{\beta} z_2  } \end{array}\right) $$

You can see that the $z_1$ and $z_2$ are mixed in the same way for both transformations.

---

It doesn't cause any difficulty if we allow the quadratic form $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$ to equal any real number.

The transformation matrices would remain the same.

$$ \left( \begin{array} \ \alpha & - \bar{\beta} \\ \beta & \bar{\alpha} \end{array}\right) \qquad |\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1,$$

The spinors would still be expressible as $2\times 2$ matrices.

$$ \left( \begin{array} \ z_1 & - \bar{z_2} \\ z_2 & \bar{z_1} \end{array}\right)$$

Comment: "SU(2) can be defined as the group of determinant-1 transformations which leaves,

|z1|2+|z2|2=1,


invariant.", But i read in a book that matrix which preserve quadratic form (  |z1|2+|z2|2  )  invarient  is called SU (2)  Can you please clarify me @  Spencer

Comment: Can we represent a vector defined over the field of real numbers in spinor notation

Comment: With regards to the definition of SU(2). It doesn't change the matrices, but it does change your space of spinors slightly. I will amend my answer to accommodate this.

Comment: With regards to real numbers, you certainly can define spinors that way. If a spinors is described by a pair of complex numbers, then it can be described by 4 real numbers. Your SU(2) matrices would have to be 4x4 in that case.

Comment: how will you orient 3 components of vector in a spinor matrix ?@ Spencer

Comment: @Robin You can use the Pauli matrices to represent a vector in 2x2 form - see the section "Pauli vector" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Comment: Is 2by2 matrix correspond to a vector in complex space is a rank 2  tensor in complex space of 2 dimensions , isn't it ?

Comment: @robin with regards to your other inquiries it would be appropriate to post a new question; as they stray outside the scope of this one.